# Multiple connections to database in BPMN diagram

Tags: bpmn, signavio

[image: An example of a BPMN model, with a lot of connections to the database]

I'm working on a BPMN model of an application of a library with a lot of connections to the database (almost in every process). I'm using an online modelling tool (Signavio) to construct the model, but it is impossible to connect all lines in a clean way.

Therefore I'm wondering if there are alternatives to this, maybe in the process itself a symbol that a connection to the database is made, one database symbol with a lot of lines from and to it (although this remains an unclean solution).

Comment: Please, insert your image inline, not as a link.

Comment: Add more space to the model between the elements, should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks you, I'll keep this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

For the most processes it is possible to construct a model and connect all lines in a clean way. If you have got a lot of overlapping lines, try to re-think your process logic. Perhaps it is possible to combine or reduce some activitys. You can also try to work with BPMN subprocesses to create a better overview of your main process by outsourcing something. Space between elements is also a big thing, like [Zelldon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2165134/zelldon) mentioned in the [comment section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43659434/multiple-connections-to-database-in-bpmn-diagram#comment74396802_43659434). Another point is using straight lines without kinks (if you need to pass a corner, make a straight 90 degree kink).

If you are using Signavio for modelling, try using the integrated validation tool. Actually it gives you some tips to order your lines to create a better looking process diagram.